# .htaccess rewrite_mod for legacy URLs using variables

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am struggling with some legacy URLs and can't get my rewrite_mod to work. This is what I am trying to do: Redirect anything from

domain.com/profile/* to domain.com/profile/2012/*

AND and the same time

domain.com/profile/team/* to domain.com/profile/2011/*

(the Asterisk stands for any name, a single word).

Thanks for any help!
Best, Roman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/profile/team/(.+)$ /profile/2011/$1

RedirectMatch 301 ^/profile/([^/]*)/?$ /profile/2012/$1
```

Comment: Hey, that is very close! It actually works, but seems to also add an argument ?q=profile/* after the newly created (redirected) URL. The redirected URL is actually the one I want to have, but I am getting a 404 since "?q=profile" is not a valid URL.

Comment: Oh OK looks like you some exceeding rules also in your htaccess can you move these rules before any other rules you have in there.